# Mongoose on c9 how to fix

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I didn't close my `mongod` when closing the laptop and now its giving me an error. On top of that, I delete the mongod data directory with all my data in it. Now I can start up my apps using node js - is there anyway to fix this or do I need to redo all my app.js again?

> Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/workspace/RESTful/RESTful
>   Routing/RESTfulBlogApp/cats.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
>       at startup (node.js:139:18)
>       at node.js:968:3

Comment: Does the file exists cats.js exist at the path you are looking at? I am not sure if the description and the error message are related.

Comment: Hi - I edited your question to put the blockquote error lines onto separate lines; they were being all concatenated together before. By the way, there's one sentence I'm not sure about - do you mean to say _I can start up my apps_ or _I can't start up my apps_ ?

Answer (score 0):

All the files which are required in your `node app` must be present at the time of execution.

As per the error, it is unable to find `cat.js` in the required folder. You need to create again all the required files, and if they were your dbSchema, i would suggest you create your schemas again before running the app.